# Google Search Console Sitemap Can't Fetch

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, squarespace

I'm trying to get my wife's site to show up when searching google but I'm having some issues.  Her site is a Squarespace site, which creates the Sitemap automagically.  I've submitted this through the Google Search Console but it has a status of "Can't Fetch".  I tried to do a live inspection of the sitemap but that won't work as it has the NOINDEX tag.  Is there some trick to getting Squarespace sitemaps to work with google?

Her site was previously hosted by GoDaddy, domain still is for now, and was showing up on the first page of google regularly.

Comment: Just to get bases covered, you are using 'yoursite.com/sitemap.xml' as the URL for the sitemap, correct? Like this (which is for Squarespace itself, but obviously you'd insert your own site): https://www.squarespace.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  well, it's the full link. http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Thanks. Let's also confirm: the site is not password protected (see 'visibility setting' in Squarespace) and is on a paid plan (that is, not in trial mode), correct? Finally, when you go to the sitemap.xml in your browser, do you see the sitemap, as expected (similar to the Squarespace sitemap example in my first comment) or do you see something else?

Comment: Both of those are also correct.  Site Visibility is set to public and it's a paid plan.

Comment: Finally, when you go to the sitemap.xml in your browser, do you see the sitemap, as expected (similar to the Squarespace sitemap example in my first comment) or do you see something else?

Comment: I see the sitemap and verified the XML on one of the XML Verify sites.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91940/discussion-between-brandon-and-mrtcs).

Answer (score 3):

This is an error of Google new search console. I've been struggling with the same error for the past days. Doing all sorts of useless things. If you look on the google forums you'll see tons of people complaining. Experts are saying it's on google. Your sitemap is in fact pending but shows as error for some reason. Just don't resubmit it (it would reset the query). Google must fix this on their end.

Reference: https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/3280971?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on Google's side, not yours. We had the same issue with several clients' websites, Google keeps promising to solve it but no luck so far. Try submitting each page manually:

1. Go to URL INSPECTION
2. Type in the URL
3. Click REQUEST INDEXING

Extra manual work of course, but a temporary solution until Google sorts it out.